Unknown tool. Not sure what this tool is, found it in a tin of odds and ends
What is this tool? Found it in a tin of odds and ends. Only about a quarter inch across.


What material? ...Though tool id is really not in scope for a home improvement stack, we've tolerated it in the past.

It's an punch or anvil for some purpose. Can be bearings, can be buttons in clothes.

Can you flip it over and take a photograph of the other end for us, please?

I believe it to be steel and hardend.

Couple more pictures as requested.

Since you found the tools in a can of misc. stuff, it's possible that the thing to the left does not belong with the two things to the right.
The tool to the left looks like a mechanic's tool used to install a bearing race.
The tools to the right are definitely markers to align holes when doing dowel joinery.
You make a hole in one piece of wood, then drop the marker in that hole. Then align the next piece of wood and press it against the pointy end of the tool, thus marking the center of where the hole belongs in the second piece. Then insert a dowel and glue to join the pieces.

OP says it's only about 1/4 inch across.   That can't be a bearing race tool being that small.

@RMDman you're probably right, but it sure looks like this https://www.southcentraloutboards.com/379248-johnson-evinrude-bearing-race-installer-tool-b69-5252

@RMDman bearings come in many sizes - I installed a 6mm ID bearing in a bike jockey wheel this afternoon.

@Cheery,  I agree it does look like your supplied info.  I stand corrected.

It does look like the picture in your link.

@ChrisWakefield I updated my answer. The other tools in your updated picture are definitely furnituremaker's marking tools

What's the thing half out of shot on the right ?  Is it a matching fir for the other piece?    If yes, my answer is "eyelet installer" or "grommit installer"
These are used to install eyelets/grommits or press studs into fabric, to reinforce a hole for rope, or to clip a flap down.

Negative point is that I can't see a curve or recess in your photo on the horizontal lands anywhere.

New photos show a point on the other side of two of them.  Those two are a kind of transfer marker, often used to align dowell holes when doing joinery.  Sometimes called a "dowel center" too
The carpenter would drill a series of holes into one piece of wood to be joined, and then insert one of these transfer plugs into each hole.  Then the other piece of wood would be offered up and lightly tapped with a mallet to make an indent, showing a center point for the other half of the drilled hole.
Then the dowells and glue are added and the whole thing clamped up till the glue dries.
 

This doesn't cover the first item, the one without a point.
